# Display Random Products on CMS Page

Tags: cms, products, random

I used this code `{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="3"}}`. Thats Works fine, but there is a Problem. If you open my CMS Webpage http://shop.blog-mvc-computertechnik.de you will see the format is wrong. if you call other articels the are formatted normal. Whats wrong?

Comment: i  have chech there are only one issue  and it design

Comment: If you look at the Startpage you will see the formatted from the articel is wrong. If you look at antoher, perhaps symantec, the format is right from the articel

Answer (score 1):

You have some styles on the `.std ul` selector in styles.css.

```
.std ul {
    list-style: disc outside;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

I don't recommend removing them since they might have some use in other pages.
Instead add this to the same css file:

```
.cms-index-index .std ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but no change... :-(

Comment: Okay i found that the CMS Page use the Body Class <body class=" cms-index-index cms-home"> and the another Pages use <body class=" catalog-category-view>. Where i can change these?

Comment: @MarkoVinogradac. You cannot change the body class. I mean you can but it's not a good practice and it takes a lot of code. I edited my answer. See if this works for you.

Comment: Hello thanks, but not working. I i have another idea.Copy the exist list.phtml and rename to list_1.phtml. Can force only list mode?